# PHP: What is the best and easiest way to check if directory is empty or not

Tags: php, directory, removeall, is-empty

I got a root directory with 100s of dynamically generated folders. As time goes some of these folders will need to be extirpated from system on the condition that this(ese) directories(s) must be empty. What would be the best shortest, easiest and/or most effective way to achieve that?

Comment: [`rmdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) will fail for non-empty directory, so just `$deleted = @rmdir('/path/to/folder');`

Comment: Thanks... going the `glob` way as suggested  by both @Matteo and *Jeffman*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `glob` :

```
if (count(glob("path/*")) === 0 ) { // empty
```

A nice thing about `glob` is that it doesn't return `.` and `..` directories.

Comment: use `GLOB_NOSORT` flag to increase performance

Comment: but if ./.. are not reported, then such dir would not be deleted, as it is not empty ... so it seems to be not good for empty dir removal

Comment: This wrong way, glob() ignores hidden files by default, http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php#68869

So, if you add the mask to get hidden files in glob() you've got the same solution, as @Matteo wrote below.

Comment: Considering coding convenience this is efficient.
Considering performance this may be bad if glob first need to deliver +1000 files for each dir to check after which count tells how many files there are.

Answer (score 8):

You can count the items contained in the folder. The first two items are `.` and `..`, so just check the items count.

```
$files_in_directory = scandir('path/to');
$items_count = count($files_in_directory);
if ($items_count <= 2)
{
    $empty = true;
}
else {
    $empty = false;
}
```

Comment: Is this going to be quicker and most effective way than the `glob` suggested by @jeffman ?

Comment: I benchmarked the two solutions and actually Jeffman one's is faster (on one folder). Jeffman: `5.388E-5 seconds` My solution: `2.909E-5 seconds`

Comment: +1...for elaborating further. Thanks