# Fast test if directory is empty

Tags: r, performance, directory, is-empty

What is the fastest way to test if a directory is empty?

Of course I can check the length of

```
list.files(path, all.files = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE, no.. = TRUE)
```

but this requires enumerating the entire contents of the directory which I'd rather avoid.

**EDIT**: I'm looking for portable solutions.

**EDIT^2**: Some timings for a huge directory (run this in a directory that's initially empty, it will create 100000 empty files):

```
system.time(file.create(as.character(0:99999)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.720  12.223  14.948 
system.time(length(dir()))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.419   0.600   3.167 
system.time(system("ls | head -n 1"))
# 0
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.788   0.495   1.312 
system.time(system("ls -f | head -n 3"))
# .
# ..
# 99064
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.002   0.015   0.019
```

The `-f` switch is crucial for `ls`, it will avoid the sorting that will take place otherwise.

Comment: I just removed my comments (on linux only solutions) but You're right portability is a nice feature to have.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685576/php-what-is-the-best-and-easiest-way-to-check-if-directory-is-empty-or-not?rq=1  has a comment recommending `rmdir` which "should" fail if the directory is non-empty.  Check your permission level!

Comment: Yeah, but... is it faster for empty or "not-huge" directories, and which are you more likely to run across?  :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Yes, and bubble sort is faster than quicksort for "not-huge" data... I've wondered, I'm curious, I've posted a question. Let's wait and see if there is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about `if(length(dir(all.files=TRUE)) ==0)`  ?

I'm not sure what you qualify as "fast," but if `dir` takes a long time, someone is abusing your filesystem :-(.

Comment: The OP mentionnend that he wants to avoid enumerating the entire contents of the directory (and `dir` == `list.files`) and without `all.files = TRUE` you will miss hidden files

Comment: @dickoa good point, sorry.  But I fail to see what's so bad about enumerating (since I'm not returning an object to the environment)

Comment: Not that bad actually but may be the OP is just looking for a more efficient alternative to this solution. I use linux and for this kind of task if I want to do it fast I use the shell through `system`.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I'm really nitpicking here. Enumerating perhaps is not noticeable performance-wise expect if a slow file system is used and the directory contains many entries. (You call it "abuse", but it might happen.)

Comment: `dir` is much faster than calling the operating system yourself.  Compare `system.time(dir())` with `system.time(system("ls", TRUE))`.

Comment: But you still get `.` and `..` when you get all files.

Comment: @James --- Oh, well, guess it's still operating-system specific.

Comment: @RichieCotton: I have edited my question to add a comparison for a huge directory that shows that `system("ls | head -n 1")` can be faster than `dir()`.

Comment: `head` doesn't exist in the Windows command shell. I tried the 100k files tests under Win7 with a local SSD, and I still find `dir` to be a little quicker.  On a network drive, most of the time involves passing data across a network and it doesn't matter which solution you use.  So as with many performance questions, there are no guaranteed wins; it depends on your setup.  Interesting question though.

Comment: @RichieCotton: Sorry, it has to be `ls -f` to avoid sorting.

Comment: S/He wants to be portable, and this does not work under Windows unless you add `no.. = FALSE`