# Efficient list.files

Tags: r, system

I want to do the equivalent of `ls` in `R`.
Say I want `ls /a/b/c/201*/*/d/e/f/*/sameNameFile.gz`, this command take 5 seconds to run on a terminal, I tried to use `list.files` but it takes a `path` argument and need `recursive=TRUE`. It is taking ages...

Is there a function I could use (or an option to `list.files`) that would allow me to run this `ls` command (I know I can run the comamnd itself with `system(cmd,intern=TRUE)` but I want a R solution)

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21576944/134830

Comment: If this is a command that you have to run regularly, you might want to consider copying the files you want to a common folder, or otherwise restructuring your filing system.

Answer (score 9):

The result from the related question

[Fast test if directory is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21576944/134830)

was that on some systems, `system("ls -f -R", intern = TRUE)` is faster than `list.files`.  Your performance may vary.

The `-R` switch means recursive; the `-f` switch means don't sort alphabetically, which is where the performance gain comes from.

Comment: performance in my case is like 1 to 100 ... Also I am not using `-R` here I just specify a `regex` with the whole path... I should not have to use `recursive` in `list.files`

Comment: @statquant then don't use it. The gist of this answer is that `list.files` is slow, and something like `system(sprintf('ls %s', ls_args), intern = TRUE)` is just plain faster.

Answer (score 0):

A good and fast solution as an alternative to @Richie Cotton's answer is to use the `shell` function with the system command `find`.
This will give you the full paths of the files, and is recursive!

```
folder <- "path/to/folder/"
pattern <- "search_pattern"
files <- shell(paste("find -L", folder, "-name '",pattern,"'"),
             intern = T)
```

It is important to end the search starting folder path with "`/`" for the command to run correctly. This is not appended by default when using the R base function `file.path()`.

[Quoting the search pattern is important, as otherwise the search won't be correctly recursive.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123440/why-is-my-find-not-recursive)

`-L` flag is present to solve possible symlinks in the paths.

---

This solution took me 2 min 5 sec to search 274 400 files from a folder of totaling over 300 000 items recursively, using file extension as the search term.

Alternative formatting to the above:

```
folder <- "path/to/folder/"
pattern <- "search_pattern"
files <- shell(
           sprintf("find -L %s -name '%s'", folder, pattern),
           intern = T)
```

---

For a more familiar pattern matching you can replace the `-name` test argument with `-regex`. Quoting the pattern inside the command is then not required, but does not affect the results.